# load call back firing early

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am running into a race condition with jquery's load function.  It seems if the page takes longer to load than my animation I am shown a blank dialog.  If it loads before the animation completes everything is fine.  Why is the load callback happening before the DOM is properly updated?

```
$(function() {
    $("#diagBox").load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
        $dialog.imagesLoaded(function() {
            $dialog.dialog("option", 'show', {
                effect: "puff",
                duration: 200,
                complete: function() {
                    positionElements();
                }
            });
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            $dialog.dialog("option", "position", "center");
        });
    });
});
```

imagesLoaded is from [desandro](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

positionElements updates the size of the dialog based on its contents and updates jScrollPane, the page is blank from jScrollPane being initialized when the height of `#diagBox` is 0.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using a full $.ajax for this?  It'll give you more control over .load()

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle?

Comment: I always have trouble doing loads in jsfiddle is there an easy way to simulate this.  I always get cross site scripting errors.